# When publishing Apk there is need to publish in app products of that app?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am using in app product in my app..but i don't know is there any required to published in app products of my app which is already published in Google Play..Please Help me..Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to publish products which you are selling through in app purchase on Google Play.
You can find more details here: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-list-setup

Comment: Log in to your publisher account.
In the All Google Play listings panel, under the application name, click In-app Products.
Click Add new product (see figure 2) and provide details about the item you are selling and then click Save or Publish.

Comment: Here thay said that Click Save or Publish...?..It means if we saved then it automatically published..Right ?

Comment: You have to publish it to be available in the application itself.